# How to read Figure xx.x or Section xx.x

Tags: numbers, speech

I wonder that whether there is a special reading way pertaining to American or British.

For example,

> Figure 12.3 shows a paused video touched on in Section 2.10 with the
>   width, height, and duration showing.

Is *Figure twelve point three shows a paused video touched on in Section two point ten* right?

Comment: "12.3" could be "twelve point three".  Or "twelve dot three".  Maybe even "twelve three".  Probably there are other pronunciations as well.  But not "twenty point three" as in the question.

Comment: As a Brit I would read it as "figure twelve point three", but I have to admit I've never really considered whether that's correct. It's not something I've ever really had to read aloud before.

Comment: It shouldn't be read as X _point_ Y for two reasons: firstly the dot is not a decimal point because it is usually on the line rather than raised above it and, secondly the levelling can be extended to further terms as X.Y.Z and so on. I'm British and use X point Y for decimals but always refer to numbered paragraphs a X dot Y dot Z and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of saying this in British and Canadian English is "Figure twelve point three". I've heard it said similarly in the U.S. so I expect that to be acceptable.  I've heard "twelve dot three" occasionally too.

Comment: I have never heard that, I have to admit. I’d never even considered reading it like that, and I think I’d be quite nonplussed if I heard it. The only way I’ve ever heard it read is “figure/section twelve three”. Would you also read “question 5.B” as “question five point bee”?

Comment: That's usually acceptable too.